# Shemona Ve'esrim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred twenty-eight?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

19 solar years = 228 months. We add 7 lunar months to every 228 solar months to keep the calendar in sync.

Answer (score 4):

228 days = from Rosh Hashana through the end of Pesach.

Comment: David P. Hochman, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for your contributions to the mi.yodeya series! I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: Is that this year? There are years with 1 Adar, years with 2 Adars, years with 29/30 days in Cheshvan and Kislev.

Answer (score 3):

228 years = Vilna Gaon born 1720/5480 until State of Israel established 1948/5708.

Answer (score 3):

This year, Jews outside of Eretz Yisrael will have 228 days from the announcement of Vesein Berachah to the announcement of Vesein Tal Umatar (from the first night of Chol Hamoed, this year Apr. 20, through Dec. 5 - next year being a secular leap year).

Answer (score 2):

According to the Gemara עבודה זרה דף ט,א the world was created to last 6000 years - תנא דבי אליהו ששת אלפים  שנה הוי העולם - . We are now in the year 5771 which leaves us with 228 years + a bit.

Comment: Where does the Gemara explicitly say that this world was created to last 6000 years? Isn't that just one interpretation of terei alfei tohu, trei alfei Torah, vetrei Alfei Yemos haMoshiah among others?

Answer (score 2):

ברוך = 228

228 = בכור

228 = ברכו

Comment: Also בכרו רכבו רוכב כרוב.